# Call puppet function inside a resource to define a class atribute

Tags: puppet

I'm trying to call a new function inside a puppet resource in a manifest, but I don't know how to create a resource to assing a value retrieved from a function in a resource.

### Define the function

Directory *puppet-module/lib/puppet/parser/functions/*.

```puppet
module Puppet::Parser::Functions
  newfunction(:retrive_pub_key, :type => :rvalue, :doc => <<-EOS
    Returns content of ssh key pub file.
    EOS
  ) do |args|
    File.read(args[0])
  end
end
```

Call the function:

```puppet
$key = retrive_pub_key('/opt/ssh-keys/admin_rsa.pub')
```

How Do I call the function inside resource to define **$key** variable with rvalue ? after 'admin_rsa.pub' is created ?

### Calling the function

Inside Puppet manifest *init.pp*.

```puppet
??? {"retrieve_key":
    ???,
    ???,
    require => [File["/opt/ssh-keys/admin_rsa.pub"],
}
```

I've been following this tutorial about [functions in puppet](http://www.masterzen.fr/2011/10/29/puppet-extension-points-part-1/)

Here is [the sample project](https://bitbucket.org/ricardogarfe/gerrit-ssh-sql-template/overview) to test functionalities.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you wish to set the *content* of some file to the content of the corresponding public key file in your `/opt/ssh-keys` directory.

Would something like this work?

```puppet
file { 'admin_rsa'
    content => retrieve_pub_key("/opt/ssh-keys/${name}.pub"),
    path => '/home/admin/.ssh/id_rsa.pub',
    ....
    require => File["/opt/ssh-keys/${name}.pub"],
}
```